# Spring include relative path in properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I'm trying to make it so that in `config/app.properties`, I can have:

```
myfile.location=./myfile
```

where `.` is relative to said properties file. Is this possible ? I tried:

```
resourceLoader.getResource(appConfig.getMyFileLocation());
```

where resourceLoader and appConfig are autowired, but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I usually reference my files like this:

```
myfile.location=classpath:myfile
```

where myfile is at the same location as the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Java properties are key-value pairs. So when you specify `myfile.location=./myfile`, this means `appConfig.getMyFileLocation()` will return './myfile' which is not the correct location.

As a workaround, you can get the location of the properties file and then use it along with the relative location to find the absolute path.

```
File propertyFileDirectory = .... // get the property file directory
String myfilePath = appConfig.getMyFileLocation();
File file = new File(propertyFileDirectory, myfilePath);
```

Comment: I'd like it relative to my config file, not the root (wherever it is)

Comment: what's the ... then ? that's what missing ^^